# Since ubuntu 16.04 LTS Software Updater fails with dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg

Since ubuntu 16.04 LTS  the Software Updater  every time fails with

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured.
```

Fully entry in `/var/log/apt/term.log` is:

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.24-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-3.2 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

VirtualBox is the `VirtualBox OSE (Open Source Edition)` and I have uninstalled and reinstalled it using `sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-qt virtualbox-dkms` already.

`VirtualBox` and all virtual machines are running fine. But the above error comes up every time `Software Updater` runs.

This is not the problem with the kernel module since this loads without problems and `VirtualBox` and all virtual machines are running fine.

The "Package virtualbox-3.2" which is mentioned in the error message seems rather old. Is this a bug with `virtualbox-qt`? Or how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been some broken files that needs cleaning.
How did you uninstall virtualbox? 
Try running the following command to clean install:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove 
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it still doesn't work afterwards, can you post the output of

```
dpkg --list | grep virtualbox-qt
```

Comment: Your first suggestions I had all done already. Btw:  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` will not work, will it? But the `dpkg --list` was the right hint. Thank you for it. It told me a package `virtualbox-3.2` in package state `rc `. So the package should be removed but the removing was not made and at least the old configuration files where still there.  Then I did `sudo apt-get --purge remove virtualbox-3.2` and this seems to solved the problem now.

Comment: @AxelRichter Glad it worked! Also I apologize for giving you the deprecated command `dpkg-reconfigure -a`. I didn't know that 16.04 dropped what used to be in Trusty [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html) It seems like they removed the `-a` option.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in a similar situation when I was trying to install Virtual Box 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial on Live Persistence USB.

The following steps should help:

1. Download the `.deb` package [virtualbox.org](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) for the Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

e.g. *virtualbox-5.1_5.1.12-112440~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb*

2. Try to install the `.deb` package by

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.12-112440~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
   ```

   Or you can do :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-5.1
   ```
3. If you get error messages like :

   ```
     The following packages have unmet dependencies:  virtualbox-5.1 :
    Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
   ```

   You can get the `.deb` for `libqt5x11extras5` [from this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/libqt5x11extras5)

   When you download the necessary deb package install the package using:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libqt5x11extras5_5.2.1-1_amd64.deb
   ```
4. For `libsdl1.2debian`, you can do :

   ```
    sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian
   ```

After this retry installing virtualbox-5.1. It should work.